# Incron и python

Tags: python, linux

Вопросы:

1) Работает ли Incron с каталогами которые подключены к нему по сети?

2) Как корректно оформить код для его работы, что бы на вход он получал имя пришедшего файла, а на выходе делал файл в Windows для записи информации в него по SMB?

Код Python:

```
 #!/usr/bin/etc python
    from sys import  argv
    from os import path
    def test(arg):
        name = str(arg)
        path = '/home/egor/test2/test.txt'
        g =open(path,'a')
        g.write(name)
        g.close()
    test(argv[1])
```

Команда Incrontab:

```
/home/egor/kanopus IN_CLOSE_WRITE touch  /home/egor/kanopus/test.py $#
```

Comment: 1. [Inotify reports only events that a user-space program triggers
       through the filesystem API.  As a result, it does not catch remote
       events that occur on network filesystems.](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html)

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Работает ли Incron с каталогами которые подключены к нему по сети?

Сетевые каталоги подключаются не "к нему", а к точке монтирования. И узнать, какой каталог локальный, а какой - смонтированный сетевой можно только приложив специальные усилия. Например - просмотреть файл */etc/mtab*.

Будут ли приходить сообщения *inotify* от ФС, смонтированной по сети, зависит только от этой ФС. Я не уверен на 100%, но сильно сомневаюсь, что Windows будет посылать какие-то извещения удалённым хостам, которые смонтировали её шары.

> 2) на выходе делал файл в Windows для записи информации в него по SMB

Это вообще - про что ?! Как это "делать файл в Windows" ?! Что такое "Запись по SMB" ?!